# Make Django ORM inside celery task use unit test database

Tags: django, unit-testing, celery

In Django application I have a view which runs the Celery task.
Inside the celery task I do some actions with database using Django ORM.

I call my test case something like this:

```
class MyViewTestCase(APITestCase):
   def test_my_view(self):
       self.client.post('url',data)
```

my test case does all ORM manipulations inside the test DB.
But inside celery task all ORM actions are happening on product database.

I use celery 4.

Is there option to make celery work with test Django database?

Answer (score 0):

By default, Django uses an in-memory test database, which is not accessible by external process, such as Celery launched from the command line or daemon. However, [it is possible to launch a worker as a thread in the Django test process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46530784/make-django-test-case-database-visible-to-celery/46564964#46564964) with `celery.contrib.testing.worker.start_worker`, which will use the test database as desired.